# Porting tufte-book title page in book class

Tags: titles, tufte

How can I get the same title page produced by

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\author{An author}
\title{A title}
\publisher{A publisher}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

while using the standard `book` class? I tried copy pasting the code for the tufte-book title page, which is

```
\newcommand{\maketitlepage}[0]{%
  \cleardoublepage%
  {%
  \sffamily%
  \begin{fullwidth}%
  \fontsize{18}{20}\selectfont\par\noindent\textcolor{darkgray}{\allcaps{\thanklessauthor}}%
  \vspace{11.5pc}%
  \fontsize{36}{40}\selectfont\par\noindent\textcolor{darkgray}{\allcaps{\thanklesstitle}}%
  \vfill%
  \fontsize{14}{16}\selectfont\par\noindent\allcaps{\thanklesspublisher}%
  \end{fullwidth}%
  }
  \thispagestyle{empty}%
  \clearpage%
}
```

but the command `\allcaps` is not defined in the book class. Also, the font seems to be different than the standard Computer Modern.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are commands there that are defined by the `tufte-book` class. The `\sfffamily` font is defined in your document, if you don't do anything it will be the default Computer Modern Sans in the `book` class.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
\setsansfont{TeX Gyre Heros}

\newcommand{\allcaps}[1]{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=8}\MakeUppercase{#1}}



\makeatletter
\newcommand{\@publisher}{}
\newcommand*{\publisher}[1]{\gdef\@publisher{#1}}

\renewcommand{\maketitle}{%
  \begin{titlepage}
  \setlength{\parindent}{\z@}
  \raggedright
  \sffamily  
  \fontsize{18}{20}\selectfont\par\noindent\textcolor{darkgray}{\allcaps{\@author}}%
  \vspace{11.5pc}%
  \fontsize{36}{40}\selectfont\par\noindent\textcolor{darkgray}{\allcaps{\@title}}%
  \vfill%
  \fontsize{14}{16}\selectfont\par\noindent\allcaps{\@publisher}%
  \end{titlepage} 
}

\makeatother

\title{A great, informative title to call attention}
\author{The author} \publisher{The Publisher} 

\begin{document}

\maketitle


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's almost identical except for the spacing between words, which is a too little when using the `book` class. How can I fix that?

Comment: @noibe, see my updated answer. You can change the spacing between letters to your taste. I did it with `fontspec`, so you must compile with `xelatex` or `lualatex`. It is also possible to use the `pdflatex`-way with the `soul` or  `letterspace` packages, as defined in the `tufte-common.def` file.